# Selecting rows with id's that are found in a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql

I am wondering how i can find all rows that have the same ID as one of the values in an array.. so lets say:

```
Array(1,2,5,6,99,467);
```

Now i want to query all rows which have an id in that array, my initial idea was to loop the array and use a SELECT on each field, but i  am wondering if i can skip that process with some kind of in_array method to make a bit more efficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE id IN (' . implode(', ', $arr) . ')
```

PS: if the data comes from outside and can contain non-numbers - it could worth performing `array_map('intval', $arr)` before

Comment: If i am using PDO for my queries, like this:
$stmt->execute(array($array_data));

Will that still escape the array data for safe input ?

Comment: @Dave: PDO doesn't have facilities for sanitizing the data presented as array. You need to do that yourself. PS: it doesn't accept arrays as a parameters as well

Comment: how would i sanitize the data inside the array before hand ?

Comment: @Dave: If there are only numbers in array - then just `$arr = array_map('intval', $arr);`

Comment: @Dave For PDO prepared query: `$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (".implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($arr), '?')).")"); $stmt->execute($arr);`

Comment: @DaveRandom: prepared statements in this case aren't better in any way than just a plain generated query. But indeed - if someone wants prepared statement - it is a solution

Comment: @zerkms I know I thought that as I wrote it - but it could potentially be useful if you have to insert multiple rows based on many arrays of a fixed length, or if you want to allow non-numeric types. It does cut out the `array_map()` call, but I suspect that what you gain there would be lost on the `array_fill()` plus the additional round trip to the DB.